# How to get value of a dynamically generated hidden input using jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am generating a list of users dynamically. One of the values I am generating is the id of the user's house. I am trying to get the value of a hidden input field so that I can get the id of the user's house so I can send that id to my php code and block that particular house. Right now I get the value of the first hidden input that is generated even when I click on a button to block a different house.

So how can i get a value of a hidden dynamically generated input field on a click of a button?

Dynamically generated part from the database:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($houses_array); $i++) {


    if ($houses_array[$i]['verify_status'] === 1) {
        $verify_text = "User is verified";
    } else {
        $verify_text = "User is not verified";
    }

    if ($houses_array[$i]['role'] === 1) {
        $role_text = "House admin";
    }

    if ($houses_array[$i]['role'] === 1) {
        $role_text = "Regular user";
    }


    if ($houses_array[$i]['first_login'] === null) {
        $first_login_text = "User logged in for the first time";
    } else {
        $first_login_text = "User has yet to login";
    }

    if ($houses_array[$i]['blocked'] === 1) {
        $blocked_text = "House is blocked";
    } else {
        $blocked_text = "House is not blocked";
    }

    echo '<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="parent"><b>House name:</b> ' . $houses_array[$i]['household_name'] . '</h5>
            <form action="" id="hidden">
            <input type="hidden" class="house_id" id="house_id" value="' . $houses_array[$i]['household_id'] . '">
            </form>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Blocked:</b> ' . $blocked_text . '</p>
        <button type="submit" name="block_btn" class="btn btn-danger block" id="block_btn">Block house</button>
        <button type="submit" name="unblock_btn" class="btn btn-success unblock" id="unblock_btn" style="margin-left: 20px">Unblock house</button>
        <br><br>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Users email:</b> ' . $houses_array[$i]['users_email'] . '</p>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Full name:</b>  ' . $houses_array[$i]['full_name'] . '</p>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Verification status:</b>  ' . $verify_text . '</p>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Users\'s role:</b> ' . $role_text . '</p>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Time of sign in:</b> ' . $houses_array[$i]['date_time_signup'] . '</p>
        <p class="card-text"><b>First login:</b>  ' . $first_login_text . '</p>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Users\'s ip address:</b> ' . $houses_array[$i]['ip_adress'] . '</p>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Users\'s web browser and OS:</b> ' . $houses_array[$i]['web_browser_OS'] . '</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        
    </div>
</div>';
}
?>
```

This is how I am currently getting the value of a hidden input field, but it's not working like it's supposed to because it grabs the previous input field from aboive the one I am clicking on.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".block").click(function () {
            console.log(123123)

            let data = $("#hidden").serializeArray();
            console.log(data)
            // let house_id = $("#parent > input").val();

            console.log(house_id);

            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "block_house.php",
                data: {
                    house_id: house_id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })
        }); $(".block").click(function () {
            console.log(123123)

            let data = $("#hidden").serializeArray();
            console.log(data)
            // let house_id = $("#parent > input").val();

            console.log(house_id);

            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "block_house.php",
                data: {
                    house_id: house_id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })
        });

}
```

Comment: `$("#hidden")` - without looking too closely, I would say that you have `<input id=hidden` (**edit** it's a form, but close) on every row / "card".  IDs must be unique, `$("#hidden")` will always get the first one.   Use `this` and relative navigation within your click handler, eg `$(this).closest(".card-body").find("form")`

Comment: Alternatively, add the id to the button and forget the hidden form, it's confusing.   `<button type="submit" name="block_btn" class="btn btn-danger block" id="block_btn" data-house-id="' . $houses_array[$i]['household_id'] . '">Block house</button>` then `$(this).data("house-id")`

Comment: @freedomn-m I understand the part with the button but could you be a little more specific with the jquery part? I am quite new to jquery so I don't know it all to well, thanks

Comment: @freedomn-m I am particularly confused by this part data-house-id="' . $houses_array[$i]['household_id'] . '"

Comment: @freedomn-m I didn't quite understand what your particularly suggested but your suggestion did show me what I needed to do. I added yhis to my button value="' . $houses_array[$i]['household_id'] . '" and then grabbed the that value in jquery like this   $(".block").click(function () {
            console.log(123123)

            let house_id = $(this).val();
}
.block is the class of the block button. So thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, essentially the same, but rather than (rendered) `<button value='123'` you can add it as a data attribute to be more descriptive (and be able to add multiple values), eg `<button data-house-id='123'` - the `' . $houses_array` was the php part that you already had in your form.

Comment: The `let house_id = $(this).data("house-id");` to read the `data-house-id` attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245413/discussion-between-janosz--and-freedomn-m).

Answer (score 0):

in your block_house.php get the house_id like so $house_id = $_POST["house_id"];

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".block").click(function () {


            $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "block_house.php",
                data:$("#hidden").serialize();,
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })
        });
```